Opening chrome profile and navigating to a webpage with puppeteer
I am trying to create a script that would automatically open my chrome browser using my default chrome profile and redirect to a webpage. However, I am currently having a problem with my code


const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath:
      "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
    userDataDir: "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data",
    args: ["--profile-directory=Default"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  await page.goto(<webpagelink>);



I have noticed that when I specify the chrome profile to be used, it opens the correct chrome profile but redirects me to an empty page and returns this error:
file:///C:/Users/xxxx/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/es
m/launch.js:301
reject(new Error([
^
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting
at ChildProcess.onClose (file:///C:/Users/xxxx/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/esm/launch.js:301:24)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:531:35)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)

On the other hand, when I remove the userDataDir and args / do not specify the chrome profile, and just let it open a chrome browser it works and redirects me to the webpage.
What could be the problem?
I tried removing the specific chrome profile, and it works. But I want it to open a specific chrome profile.
